# What is the "View" in MVP pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, mvp

From some tutorials  I cant understand what mean "View". More accurately -   I cant understand how many views can displays at same time? In tutorials what I read, only 1 view displays at same time, and it always occupies full screen. For example if I need show popup panel, it is normally to make new view for this popup panel? or better to include this popup panel into another view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show as many Views as you need, it is not about MVP pattern. From View perspectives MVP describes relation between Model-View-Presenter, but any View could have child Views with own presenters and bound model.

So common scenario - having main View which divides own space/layout between set of child views each of them has own Presenter and uses own/shared model (depends on application specifics and design).

Answer (score 1):

This completely depends upon the implementation that you use.

For instance, an ASP.NET MVC implementation may contain multiple partial views that are displayed simultaneously (although there will be only one main View, that is, the page) while a desktop application may manage multiple open windows which each have their own dedicated View. A smartphone app then probably has only one active View open at any time...

Answer (score 1):

In theory, I suppose View is the representation of models. You make some data conversions and calculations from the model, extract data from them and put in a nice format in views.

In practice, View is everything that user sees. JFrame(Java), Activity(Android), Windows Forms are examples of views.

Answer (score 1):

> For example if I need show popup panel, it is normally to make new
>   view for this popup panel? or better to include this popup panel into
>   another view?

If treat the popup as just a part of a calling view then I would recommend you to keep the view in case of the popup show.

P.S.
Also conceptually you may treat a view as a tree of UI components.
In your case, for example, the tree may consist of two UI components.
Let's call first one ApplicationWindow and second one (which is shown in the popup) PatientEditor.
PatientEditor is a child of ApplicationWindow and so it's ok to show it in the same view (tree of UI components).